# Narrowing conversion of list initialization is an error or just a warning?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

Currently I was self-learning C++ primer 5th edition. The text says:

> When used with variables of built-in type, this form of initialization has one
>   important property: The compiler will not let us list initialize variables of built-in type if
>   the initializer might lead to the loss of information:

Here is the example code:

```
long double ld = 3.1415926536;
int a{ld}, b = {ld}; // error: narrowing conversion required
int c(ld), d = ld; // ok: but value will be truncated
```

But when I tried it myself on C++shell:

```
long double a=3.14159265354;
 int b(a);
 int c{a};
 std::cout<<a<<std::endl<<b<<std::endl<<c<<std::endl;
```

It simply gives a warning of `-Wnarrowing`but the program successfully executed. Why?

Comment: In general, for violations of the language rules, the C++ standard requires that the compiler issue a diagnostic. It did that. The standard does not distinguish between warnings and errors, and does not require any particular behavior after issuing the diagnostic.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh, thank you for point it out!

Comment: @NathanOliver I did try to find out the answer on FAQ but it's so difficult considering his question title. Anyway next time I will try to be more careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Standard specifies that a **diagnostic** is required in case that a program is ill-formed. Which is the case when a narrowing-conversion takes place inside a braced-initializer.

That is, the standard doesn't distinguish between an error and a warning.

*1.3.6 diagnostic message [defns.diagnostic]*

> message belonging to an implementation-defined subset of the
>   implementation's output messages

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think this question should be closed already..

Comment: @Des1gnWizard you can effectively "close" the question by accepting this answer. Just click on the hollow checkmark to the left, so that it becomes green.

Comment: @Dialecticus Thank you so much for pointing this out.....Thanks..